# Odoo 13 import products with variants

Tags: import, product, variant, odoo-13

can someone help me I'm trying to import product with variants into odoo 13 and I can't figure it out how to add details about the variant like default_code.
this is the csv:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apByx.png)

all the attributes and attribute values are created.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can try to export all fields first in csv mode file and rewrite your data that you want and import it ,
it will work